# -くて, -なくて forms of adjectives

Tags: て-form, negation, i-adjectives

I got confused by these forms. The book says that -くて(pos) and -なくて(neg) have to be connected with stem of an adjective, e.g. 安い: 安 ＋ くて ＝ 安くて.

The positive form is pretty easy to understand and master, but the negative one is a trouble for me. Basically, I got confused by an adjective 「汚い」. Its positive form would be 「汚くて」. But would the negative be 「汚なくて」? The reasons I got confused are that IME did not recognize the negative form, and those multiple 「な」 sound a bit odd to me.

Even google barely helped me with any of the i-adjectives in -なくて form　except for 「おいしい」that was found accidentally [here](http://lang-8.com/723613/journals/338597765945707555656677684121341724768).

So, I wonder if I can add -なくて to ANY of the i-adjectives and be good with it.

And the last question. Is it actually -なくて form, or is it -くなくて?

Comment: What's the list of (mixed *i* and *na*) adjectives for?

Comment: I just supposed that there are some exceptions to the rule and thought that it would be nice to have it added here so the people could take the examples from there

Comment: But since there's no need in it, I will delete it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The negation, -くない, is itself an い-adjective. So you simply apply the rule to it. Welcome to piling up suffixes!

て-form of 安い: 安くて.

Negation of 安い: 安くない. て-form thereof: 安くなくて.

Voilà.

Comment: Just like I thought. Alas, I needed an extra explanation to this since the book has not given it. Thank you